# Qgis 2.8.9-Wien Attribute table Update Fields Error

Tags: qgis-2

I can't update fields in the Attribute table. I get an error when I select Update All and Update Selected:

An error occurred while evaluating the calculation string:
No root node! Parsing failed?

Instead I have to open Field Calculator/Select the field/re-enter the function/and hit OK for the field to be updated in the Attribute table. I can work with this but it's frustrating!

[image: UpdateFieldsError]

Comment: Is upgrading QGIS an option? It's already at 2.16, so you're using a pretty old version.

Comment: i have had the issue as well in recent 2.18